# Certain permissions to document library and the subsites

Tags: permissions, sub-site

Hope all you geniuses can help :)

I would like to give our external contractors access to a document library which we have named 'Technical Docs' - Which is fine as I can go into "site contents" > pick out the webpart > Settings and provide permission to just that one document library. Easy :)

However now the painful part... How do I add users/groups which are linked to the site we have 50+ subsites

Would I need to go into every subsite and do the above or is there an easier way?

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If the sub sites are inheriting permissions from the root parent site.then giving permissions at the root site via group should be sufficient - simplest way

If not there is no other easy way as you need to give either manually to each sub site or write a custom powershell /C# console via object model or CSOM and give the permissions through code.